# How to remove all records in a RDD including null?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, rdd

I loaded an `RDD` from a csv file. However, this file includes invalid data. So, when I tried to output the contact of this `RDD` with `first`. The exception is

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

I hope to find solution to remove all records in the `RDD` when one record includes empty string. In addition, this `RDD` includes so many fields, so it is difficult to handle every field one by one. I remembers that `DataFrame` has such function, such as [`na.drop()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@drop():org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame). I need that this kind of function will work for `RDD`.

The code I used is like:

```
//using case class
case class Flight(dest_id:Long, dest:String, crsdeptime:Double, deptime:Double, depdelaymins:Double, crsarrtime:Double)

//defining function
def parseFlight(str: String): Flight = {
  val line = str.split(",")
  Flight(line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3), line(4).toInt, line(5).toLong)
}

//loading data
val textRDD = sc.textFile("/root/data/data.csv")
val flightsRDD = textRDD.map(parseFlight)
```

**update**

When I used RDD converted by DateFrame. I found every line of RDD is Row object. How to extract some fields of one Row to build Edge object?

Comment: Why only RDD ? Why not Data frame?

Comment: I am building graph with RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header in the csv file matches the variable names in the case class, then it's easier to read the data as a dataframe and then use `na.drop()`.

```
val flightsDf = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("/root/data/data.csv")
  .na.drop()
  .as[Flight]
```

If you want a rdd, it is always possible to convert it afterwards with `flightsDf.rdd`.

Comment: I found that every line of this rdd is one Row object. How to extract fields from this Row?

Comment: @IvanLee The easiest fix to this is to change the order of the `na.drop()` and `as[Flight]`, I changed the answer above to follow this. Instead of Row objects you should have an `RDD[Flight]`.